# Plot Clustering Datapoints Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm doing a clustering exercise and I have a list that looks something like this

```
[

[(1, 3), (2, 5), (2, 6), (1, 2), (1, 8)],

[(4, 7), (5, 5), (6, 4)]

[(8, 9), (10, 9), (11, 12), (10, 12)]


[(18, 20), (20, 29), (17, 16), (18, 22)]

]
```

Basically I made the clusters into an array of arrays. I was wondering how to plot this on Python, where different clusters have different colors. I've tried using mathplotlib, but I'm quite confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `plt.scatter`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
s = [[(1, 3), (2, 5), (2, 6), (1, 2), (1, 8)], [(4, 7), (5, 5), (6, 4)], [(8, 9), (10, 9), (11, 12), (10, 12)], [(18, 20), (20, 29), (17, 16), (18, 22)]]
c = iter(['b', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'k', 'w'])
for group in s:
   plt.scatter(*zip(*group), color = next(c))

plt.show()
```

[image]